# How do I get MicroPython back?

Tags: pycharm, micropython

I installed the MicroPython package in my installation of PyCharm...all well and good.  Flashed the default script to my Raspberry Pi Pico, and after finding the MicroPython repl, and executing a soft reset, saw the appropriate output in the repl.

Then I edited main.py and re-flashed it.  Uh oh...

The repl reported that it had been interrupted...

Tried Ctrl-D...nothing

Tried to find a way to restart the repl...couldn't...

Tried hiding the MicroPython thingy (Big M in the side panel), which it did...and now I don't know how to get it back.  And I still don't know how to restart the interrupted repl.

Help?